# How can I make my tile open up the wireless toggle menu?

Tags: windows-phone-7

As a small test app I want to create a app that creates tiles for wifi, bluetooth.

By clicking one of these tiles its windows phone menu should open? There are alot of these apps in the marketplace, but how do they bypass their own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ConnectionSettingsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and fire it automatically after launching your app. You can choose which Connection Setting will be opened using [`ConnectionSettingsType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstype) enumeration.

Comment: But will not my app be running? I want to close it so that tapping the tile opens up the menu and dont force me to also close my app

Comment: Yes, you're app will still be running, but you can use `NavigationService` to remove all back entries, so user won't even notice that your app was opened.

Comment: where do i check this? Not in my page constructor :D

Comment: You probably should do it in `OnNavigatedTo` method.